# PostgreSQL - Create randomized percentages?

Tags: postgresql

For testing purposes I need to create a JSONB object with `n` random percentages, **so that they sum up to `1.0`**.

Obviously, the very simple

```
SELECT jsonb_object(array_agg(ARRAY['prefix_' || n::TEXT, round(random()::NUMERIC, 2)::TEXT])) AS e
FROM   generate_series(1,8) AS n
;
```

will produce numbers that won't sum up to `1.0`.

I expect the solution to be much more complicated, and I can't seem to put my head around this.

How to do this in PostgreSQL 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to adjust the values.

You could base your generator on this query:

```
WITH r AS (
   SELECT random()
   FROM generate_series(1, 8)
)
SELECT random/sum(random) OVER ()
FROM r;
```